# Verificar se é uma conta válida

Tags: php, eval

Estou fazendo uma consulta MySQL em que uma das colunas seria o resultado de um cálculo. 
Porém, preciso antes verificar pelo PHP se essa conta é válida. Por exemplo, pow(-0.2,0.5) seria um valor impossível pois seria o mesmo que tentar tirar a raiz quadrada de um valor negativo. Tenho um problema também que nesse campo não necessariamente precisa ser uma conta, pode ser que venha apenas como o nome de alguma coluna da tabela. 
Pensei em usar o eval(), mas ele dá erro para todas as vezes que não insiro uma conta e sim o nome de uma coluna.
Existe algum jeito para validar se é um cálculo possível e, caso seja um nome qualquer, não fazer nada?  
EX: select pow(-0.2,0.5),colunaA,colunaB from Tabela1 where nome="João" resultaria em erro já que a primeira conta é impossível. Mas pode ser que venha no seguinte formato: select pow(colunaA,colunaB),colunaA,colunaB from Tabela1 where nome="João" e nesse caso, não seria necessário fazer uma verificação se é uma conta válida.

Comment: Pode mostrar um pouco de código? ficaria mais fácil de entender a pergunta..

Comment: poderia verificar com um is_numeric o resultado, mas ai, mesmo ele sendo uma fração enoorme, seria apontado como true.

Comment: Usar o is_numeric acredito que não vai funcionar pq usando o is_numeric(eval('return '.$conta.';')) ele acusa como true mesmo sendo uma conta impossível

Answer (score 0):

Você quer resolver o problema pelo php ou mysql? Além disso, acredito que não exista o que você quer, provavelmente vai ter que fazer uma serie de validações.

mysql:

```
select if(colA >= 0, pow(colA,ColB), 'NAN') from tabelaA where nome = 'joao';
```

Se for no php é mais simples pois o calculo que você mandou (pow(-0.2,0.5)) não ira dar um erro, ele te retornara NAN. Em outros caso como por exemplo tirar a raiz de um número é só verificar se ele não é < 0. Para resolver o problema da coluna não retornar um número pode usar [is_numeric](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.is-numeric.php) ou fazer um [cast](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/internals2.opcodes.cast.php)

Comment: Quero resolver pelo PHP para que chegue no MySQL de forma sempre válida. Acho que o meu principal problema é quando tento fazer um eval de coisas não numéricas, por exemplo eval('return pow(colunaA,colunaB);') que dá erro de sintaxe.

Comment: Se for isso é necessário ser feito as validações manualmente, exemplo:

    if ($colunaA >= 0) {
        eval('return pow($colunaA, $colunaB)';
    }